# Neural network references (textbooks, online courses) for beginners

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, references, natural-language, computer-vision

I want to learn Neural Networks.  I am a Computational Linguist. I know statistical machine learning approaches and can code in Python.

I am looking to start with its concepts, and know one or two popular models which may be useful from a Computational Linguistics perspective.

I browsed the web for reference and found a few books and materials.

- Ripley, Brian D. (1996) Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks, Cambridge
- Bishop, C.M. (1995) Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition, Oxford: Oxford University Press.
- some links, like [this thesis](http://cslab1.bc.edu/~csacademics/pdf/14Aslam.pdf), [these course notes](http://www.psych.utoronto.ca/users/reingold/courses/ai/cache/neural2.html) (University of Toronto Psychology Department), [these course notes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bolo/shipyard/neural/local.html) (University of Wisconsin Computer Science) and [this slideshow](http://www.coling-2014.org/COLING%202014%20Tutorial-fix%20-%20Tomas%20Mikolov.pdf) (Facebook Research).

Coursera courses are generally nice, if anyone knows anything relevant from them. I prefer materials with lucid language and ample examples.

Comment: I have tried to edit the text to make it more reasonable, feel free to amend my edits if you feel that they have changed anything in a way you do not like.

Comment: It's not apparent what you are asking. Please make explicit what you hope to learn from CV respondents.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0z_jCi0XWqI8awUuQRFnyw highly recommend this Oxford university's professor course

Comment: My initial objective is to learn the fundamentals of ANN and master one or two models to create some text mining tools, like PoS Tagging or Sentiment Analysis. Once I get slight depth I believe I may move on my own.

Answer (score 34):

You're in luck! There are an amazing number of resources available at the moment. In particular, you could look at:

- a [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks) starting soon
- a recently published [online textbook](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by some of the leaders in the field (Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville)
- these [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07916v1.pdf), and this [overview](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00726), which are more oriented towards natural language processing
- a set of [blog posts](https://colah.github.io/) with beautiful visualizations by Chris Olah
- two well-supported toolkits with python interfaces and online tutorials: [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/index.html) and [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/)

Comment: Start with a recursive neural net http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/

Comment: Read up on how it works. Then progress to non-recursive nets and back propogation finding code for each.

Comment: Can you provide authors and titles for everything that you are citing, so that your answer becomes searchable and remains useful even if some of the links go dead?

Answer (score 17):

Main references:

Courses on deep learning:

- [Andrew Ng's course on machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) has a nice introductory section on neural networks.
- Geoffrey Hinton's course: [Coursera Neural Networks for Machine Learning (fall 2012)](https://www.coursera.org/course/neuralnets)
- [Michael Nielsen's free book *Neural Networks and Deep Learning*](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com)
- Yoshua Bengio, Ian Goodfellow and Aaron Courville wrote a [book on deep learning](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/) (2016)
- [Hugo Larochelle's course (videos + slides) at Université de Sherbrooke](http://info.usherbrooke.ca/hlarochelle/neural_networks/content.html)
- [Stanford's tutorial (Andrew Ng et al.) on Unsupervised Feature Learning and Deep Learning](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Oxford's ML 2014-2015 course](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/nando.defreitas/machinelearning/)
- [NVIDIA Deep learning course (summer 2015)](https://developer.nvidia.com/deep-learning-courses)
- [Google's Deep Learning course on Udacity (January 2016)](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730)

NLP-oriented:

- [Stanford CS224d: Deep Learning for Natural Language Processing (spring 2015) by Richard Socher](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/syllabus.html)
- [Tutorial given at NAACL HLT 2013: Deep Learning for Natural Language Processing (without Magic) (videos + slides)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/courses/NAACL2013/)

Vision-oriented:

- [CS231n Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/) by Andrej Karpathy (a previous version, shorter and less polished: [Hacker's guide to Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/neuralnets/)).

Toolkit-specific tutorials:

- DL4J (Java): http://deeplearning4j.org/documentation.html
- Theano  (Python, Y. Bengio): http://deeplearning.net/
- Machine Learning with Torch7 (Lua, LeCun): http://code.madbits.com/wiki/doku.php
- H2O Deep Learning (Java): http://0xdata.com/product/deep-learning/
- Caffee (C++, UCB): http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/
- [Nervana’s Deep Learning Course](https://www.nervanasys.com/deep-learning-tutorials/)

Answer (score 6):

http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/11/seven-steps-machine-learning-python.html

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/

This has been my favorite resources. Started with the Stanford machine learning course, but prefer reading over lectures. Especially because the readings are example-based.

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: This looks potentially like a helpful answer, but it's a little ambiguous: what are these "readings" to which you refer?  To which of the two links do your comments apply?

Comment: Thank you all for your kind effort and time. Hope I can respect it by learning well.

Answer (score 3):

[Neural Networks and Deep Learning is an approachable starting-point](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/).

> Neural Networks and Deep Learning is a free online book. The book will teach you about:
>
> Neural networks, a beautiful biologically-inspired programming paradigm which enables a computer to learn from observational data
> Deep learning, a powerful set of techniques for learning in neural networks
> Neural networks and deep learning currently provide the best solutions to many problems in image recognition, speech recognition, and natural language processing. This book will teach you many of the core concepts behind neural networks and deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

For fast learning I would choose:

This Deep Learning lecture from the great teacher-researcher Nando de Freitas:
https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/nando.defreitas/machinelearning/

For practical programming theory understanding in Python this material from Andrej Karpathy:
http://cs231n.github.io/

And for NLP:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00726